# PHP - How to use isset in an Class function and not when calling the function

Tags: php

I'm using the output from an API. The data extracted is processed in one of my Classes. The output is similar to this:

```
stdClass Object
(
   [status] => error
    [redirect_url] => stdClass Object
        (
            [web] => https://example.com/signup.php
        )
)
```

I use the above in my own class `$siteItems->processData($output->status, $output->answer)`;

However when the data isn't available I get `Trying to get property 'answer' of non-object`. When I use isset and there is a bad request `$siteItems->processData(isset($output->status), isset($output->answer))` I don't get this.

Is there a way to use $siteItems->processData($output->status, $output->answer) and only use isset inside of my own class instead having to use it when calling the function.

Comment: `$answer = !empty($output->answer) ? $output->answer : '';
$siteItems->processData(isset($output->status), isset($answer));` and `empty` will take care of `isset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `processData()` is in your own class so you can change the implementation why not just have the object passed instead of the properties ...

```php
$siteItems->processData($output);
```

and in your class where `processData()` is defined, use the [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to set the variable or null otherwise. You can then check them in an `if` and perform actions based on whether they exist or not:

```php
public function processData($obj) {
  $status = (!is_null($obj->status)) ? $obj->status: null;
  $answer = (!is_null($obj->answer)) ? $obj->answer : null;

  if($status != 'error' && $answer) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I appreciate it.

Comment: I didn’t use the `??` operator because I thought it only worked on array elements, but on taking another look at the documentation it returns the value of a variable if it *is set and different from NULL*. So the ternary’s in my answer could be replaced with `$status = $obj->status ?? null;` if you’re into that syntactic sugar

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that you're not getting "answer" variable because an API returns a status error. In that case, you just need to check the status of the API.

```
$answer = $output->status === "error" ? "" : $output->answer;
$siteItems->processData($output->status, $answer);
```

You also can check if answer property exists

```
$answer = $output->status !== "error" && isset($output->answer)  ? $output->answer : "";
$siteItems->processData($output->status, $answer);
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I'm not concerned with the answer as the API is working fine. However, sometimes the property in the API does not exist and I want to see if I could incorporate the isset inside my class instead of when calling the funciton.

Comment: You can't pass isset(...) as param to your method, it's not the correct way of checking if param exists.  You can check if the answer variable exists before calling processData method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) (PHP/7.0+):

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('{
    "one": {
        "two": [
            {
                "three": "Hello, World!"
            }
        ]
    }
}');
$foo = $data->one->two[0]->three ?? '(not set)';
var_dump($data, $foo);

$data = null;
$foo = $data->one->two[0]->three ?? '(not set)';
var_dump($data, $foo);
```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/1IKLu))